Python, matplotlib generate blank window instead of showing data
My goal is to create a program that plots mass spectrometer data and allows the user to interactively click on a datum to remove it as an outlier, with "Exit", "Previous", "Next", etc buttons below the plots.
Unfortunately the script only generates the buttons, the data pane is blank.
from import_raw import get_raw_data
from select_sequences import filter_data
from interactive_plot import plot_raw_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
import tkinter as tk


def on_next():
    global current_plot_index
    current_plot_index = (current_plot_index + 1) % len(filtered_data)
    draw_plot(current_plot_index)
    update_buttons()


def on_previous():
    global current_plot_index
    current_plot_index = (current_plot_index - 1) % len(filtered_data)
    draw_plot(current_plot_index)
    update_buttons()


def on_finish():
    window.quit()


def on_exit():
    window.quit()


def update_buttons():
    global current_plot_index
    prev_button.pack_forget()
    next_button.pack_forget()
    finish_button.pack_forget()

    if current_plot_index > 0:
        prev_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    
    if current_plot_index < len(filtered_data) - 1:
        next_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    else:  
        finish_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


def draw_plot(index, canvas):
    figure, canvas = plot_raw_data(filtered_data[index], canvas)
    figure.canvas.draw()
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


matplotlib.use('TkAgg') # forces TkAgg backend to matplotlib (for MacOSX development)

# basic functions
all_data, sequence_data = get_raw_data() # get all raw data and group into sequences
filtered_data           = filter_data(all_data, sequence_data) # filter out only the selected sequences

# GUI
window = tk.Tk()
# Frame for plot and buttons
main_frame     = tk.Frame(window)
main_frame.pack()
plot_frame     = tk.Frame(main_frame)
plot_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
button_options = {'width': 10, 'height': 2}
button_frame   = tk.Frame(main_frame)
button_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

# initialization in main frame
figure = plt.figure()
canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, master=plot_frame)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

current_plot_index = 0

# initialize buttons
global prev_button, exit_button, next_button, finish_button
prev_button   = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Previous", command=lambda: on_previous(), **button_options)
exit_button   = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Exit", command=lambda: on_exit(), **button_options)
next_button   = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Next", command=lambda: on_next(), **button_options)
finish_button = tk.Button(button_frame, text="Finish", command=lambda: on_finish(), **button_options)

prev_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
exit_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
next_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
finish_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

update_buttons()
draw_plot(0, canvas)
window.mainloop()

I can confirm that interactive_plot.py (below) generates the correct figure.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler


# this finds the closest datum to the click point
def find_closest_point(data, click_coords, mass, scaler):
    scaled_data   = scaler.transform(data[mass][['time_sec', mass]])
    scaled_click  = scaler.transform([click_coords])
    x_diff        = np.abs(scaled_data[:,0] - scaled_click[0, 0])
    y_diff        = np.abs(scaled_data[:,1] - scaled_click[0, 1])
    distances     = np.sqrt(x_diff**2 + y_diff**2)
    closest_index = distances.argmin()

    print("closest_index:", closest_index)

    return closest_index

# what to do when the user clicks on the plot
def on_click(event, data_entry, fig, canvas):
    click_coords   = (event.xdata, event.ydata)
    active_subplot = event.inaxes
    mass           = active_subplot.get_title()

    # disallow clicks on restricted plots
    if mass in ['5 amu', '4/3 Ratio']:
        if mass == '5 amu':
            messagebox.showinfo('Instructions', 'Removing baseline data is forbidden.')
        else: # 4/3 Ratio
            messagebox.showinfo('Instructions', 'Removing 4/3 Ratio data is forbidden. Remove data from 3 amu or 4 amu, rather than from the 4/3 Ratio directly.')
        return # prevents further code execution/plot updates.

    # produce a scale for the data so that the least squares fit works
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(data_entry.raw_data[mass].values)

    # determine the index of the closest datum to the click
    closest_index = find_closest_point(data_entry.raw_data, click_coords, mass, scaler)

    # toggle the clicked datum between 1 (active) and 0 (inactive)
    data_entry.data_status[mass].iloc[closest_index] = (data_entry.data_status[mass].iloc[closest_index] + 1) % 2

    # if any datum is excluded from 3 amu or 4 amu, also exclude it from the 4/3 Ratio
    if mass in ['3 amu', '4 amu']:
            data_entry.data_status['4/3 Ratio'].iloc[closest_index] = (data_entry.data_status['4/3 Ratio'].iloc[closest_index] + 1) % 2

    update_plot_and_trendlines(data_entry, fig, canvas)

# updates the plot
def update_plot_and_trendlines(data_entry, fig):

    fig.clf()
    axes = fig.subplots(2,3)
    
    # Store plot styling for each mass
    plot_kwargs = {   
        "3 amu":     {"color": "blue"},
        "4 amu":     {"color": "red"},
        "4/3 Ratio": {"color": "purple"},
        "2 amu":     {"edgecolor": "black", "facecolor": "white", "linewidth": 1},
        "40 amu":    {"color": "magenta"},
        "5 amu":     {"color": "gray"}
    }

    # loop to plot masses on the top row
    for ax, mass in zip(axes[0], ['3 amu', '4 amu', '4/3 Ratio']):

        # dress up the plot
        ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        if mass == '4/3 Ratio':
            ax.set_ylabel('4/3 Ratio * 1000')
        else:
            ax.set_ylabel('Intensity (A)')
        ax.set_title(mass)
        ax.grid(True, zorder=1)

        # define x and y
        x = data_entry.raw_data[mass]['time_sec']
        y = data_entry.raw_data[mass][mass]

        # get active indices from data_status[mass]
        active_indices = data_entry.data_status[mass].to_numpy().flatten()

        # draw trendline/average from active indices
        if mass == '4/3 Ratio':
            average_y = np.mean(y[active_indices==1])
            trend_x   = [x.min(), x.max()]
            trend_y   = [average_y, average_y]
            ax.plot(trend_x, trend_y, color="black", zorder=2)
        else: # 3 amu and 4 amu
            trend   = np.polyfit(x[active_indices==1], y[active_indices==1], 1)
            trend_x = [x.min(), x.max()]
            trend_y = np.polyval(trend, trend_x)
            ax.plot(trend_x, trend_y, color="black", zorder=2)

        ax.scatter(x[active_indices==1], y[active_indices==1], **plot_kwargs[mass], zorder=3)
        ax.scatter(x[active_indices==0], y[active_indices==0], marker='x', color='gray', zorder=3)


    # loop to plot masses in the bottom row
    for ax, mass in zip(axes[1], ['2 amu', '40 amu', '5 amu']):

        # dress up the plot
        ax.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
        ax.set_ylabel('Intensity (A)')
        ax.set_title(mass)
        ax.grid(True, zorder=1)

        # define x and y
        x = data_entry.raw_data[mass]['time_sec']
        y = data_entry.raw_data[mass][mass]

        # get active and inactive indices
        active_indices   = data_entry.data_status[mass].to_numpy().flatten()

        # draw trendline/average from active indices
        if mass == '5 amu':
            average_y = np.mean(y[active_indices==1]) if np.any(active_indices) else np.nan
            trend_x   = [x.min(), x.max()]
            trend_y   = [average_y, average_y]
            ax.plot(trend_x, trend_y, color="black", zorder=2)
        else:
            trend   = np.polyfit(x[active_indices==1], y[active_indices==1], 1)
            trend_x = [x.min(), x.max()]
            trend_y = np.polyval(trend, trend_x)
            ax.plot(trend_x, trend_y, color="black", zorder=2)

        # draw active and inactive plots
        ax.scatter(x[active_indices==1], y[active_indices==1], **plot_kwargs[mass], zorder=3)
        ax.scatter(x[active_indices==0], y[active_indices==0], marker='x', color='gray', zorder=3)


def plot_raw_data(data_entry, canvas):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(15, 8))  # Create 2x3 subplot grid
    update_plot_and_trendlines(data_entry, fig) # draw
    plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust spacing to prevent labels overlapping
    plt.suptitle(f"He {data_entry.helium_number}: {data_entry.analysis_label}")
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.92)
    #messagebox.showinfo('Instructions', 'Please inspect the data. Click on outliers to remove them.')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', lambda event: on_click(event, data_entry, fig, canvas)) # interactivity

    fig.savefig('figure.png')
    return fig, canvas

